# find table types in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my project there are thousands of sp's and 100s of them using diffrent table types as input in different procedure.I wanted to find out a list of tabletype used in particular procedure there is possiblity that a stored procedure might used multiple table types and i want all of them againts sp.

Please help me ia m not getting not to get that list.

Comment: In SSMS, right click the stored procedure and choose "view dependencies". Choose the radio button that says objects on which [your store procedure name] depends. You will see all the things this stored procedure depends on, including table types.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you a list with the procedure names, the parameter names and the corresponding types if they are table types:

```
SELECT P.[name]
      ,PM.[name]
      ,T.[name]
FROM [sys].[procedures] P
INNER JOIN [sys].[parameters] PM
    ON p.[object_id] = PM.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[types] T
    ON PM.[user_type_id] = T.[user_type_id]
WHERE T.[is_table_type] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you closer to the answer:

```
Select C.name,S.text,*
From syscomments S
inner Join sysobjects C 
on  S.id=C.id
```

Just add where closed to the query depending on you what your are looking.